# How to create a custom page that doesn't interfere with omega 3.x theme RWD

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming, responsive-design

since im new to drupal7 and omega theme, I want a custom front page, so in drupal7 I create a page--front.tpl.php and everything's ok except the responsive design of omega theme, if I dont use page--front.tpl.php it works fine, I dont know how to create a custom page without screwing omega theme's RWD. 
thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install the [Delta Module](http://drupal.org/project/delta) which will allow you to create multiple versions of your theme settings page. Think of each version of your theme settings as a new "Template" or layout for your site, since layout is primarily controlled via the zones & regions configuration options of the Omega Theme settings.

Once you have created a new Delta template for your front page, you can apply it using the [Context Module](http://drupal.org/project/context). Create a new Context for your Front Page. In this context, create a Condition first, choosing "Path" as the conditional operator and   as the path itself. Then add a "Reaction", choosing "Delta" as the reaction, and select the "Front Page Template" you just created moments ago.

Answer (score 1):

Just reuse the classes, the ids and the CSS media queries from the OMEGA theme in order to keep the Responsiveness. You need to understand how RWD works and then you can use Firebug to debug it. Do you have an online version of your work in progress?

Comment: Thanks for your answer George, unfortunately I work on localhost for now, yeah I tried what you said, it kinda works but not properly and basically it's hard to use only those CSS ID's and classes that comes with omega, it's quite simple, but mainly I have the question that how can I have custom templates, any basic sample or sth. thanks

Comment: You have to create a subtheme from OMEGA ( follow this guide: http://drupal.org/node/225125 ) this way you will be able to experiment easily with overloading (basically your modifications will have the 1st priority so they take over the omega base theme). How it works is that you use the .tpl.php files and the template.php file to shape the html exactly as you want it. If you think the OMEGA theme doesn't have classes that cover you, change them. (Although I think it should be quite good already, you have to get your CSS right..)